# Pre-Migration Risk Assessment - Vim to Neovim (5of8)

Tags: neovim, gvim, ide

*(Shared preamble)*

With my pending adoption of Ubuntu MATE 22.04, I am looking primarily at Neovim, with possible adaptation as SpaceVim/LunarVim.  I am comfortable with Vim, but am looking for a proper IDE layer for that tool of choice (I want to do some Python for CAD and Prolog for personal medical), and it **seems** from what I have come across that Neovim is the way to go.

I want to make sure that I don't jump out of the frying pan into the fire.

Are there any **gotchas** that someone evaluating such a transition needs to know **before making the move**?
Specifically...

**[5]** what things need to be "translated" to a new language in order to work in Neovim ?  Please be specific as to which languages for what specific functionality or intervention?

**Please Note:** I would ask that you please include the description of what is lacking/broken, along with the specific sequence to follow to reproduce the failed condition. That way, all can independently re-confirm, ensuring all risks associated with the migration are made explicit and facts are reliable for decision-making.